# Will not echo the new user welcome paragraph

Tags: php, welcome-file

Please any suggestion or comments here:

Login.php

```
<td width="65%" align="left">
    <input name="student_id" 
           type="text" 
           id="student_id" action="Student_Home.php" method="post">
</td>
```

Student_Home.php

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_POST["student_id"];?> </p>
```

OUTPUT:

> Welcome Notice: Undefined index: student_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\a\Student_Home.php on line 44

DESIRED OUTPUT: Welcome "student_id" !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this when taking your question in a literal way:

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo "student_id";?> </p>
```

Or, if you really refer to some id string posted by `"student_id"`, then you have to check if that member actually *is* present in the $_POST variable. The error you get indicates that currently it is *not*... Could it be that you send the html form using the GET method instead? Then you would have to use `$_GET['student_id']` obviously... Probably the best approach is to check what is actually contained in $_POST and $_GET by dumping them to some log file...

Ah, now with your edits we can see that you have a problem in your html code: the `<input>` tag does *not* offer an action and a method attribute itself! You have to enclose that tag inside an opening an a closing `<form>` tag which may carry that method information itself. So probably you are looking for something like this:

```
<form action="Student_Home.php" method="post">

    <td width="65%" align="left">
        <input name="student_id" 
               type="text" 
               id="student_id">
    </td>

</form>
```

Also a short side note: this looks like you are using a html table for page layout. That is not really good practice, though there are exceptions where this *does* make sense. In general you should do your page layout using styles, so css language instead. This keeps your page stylable and allows better interpretation by non standard browsers which is very important for example for handicapped users.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've forgotten to add a FORM element. Try this in Login.php:

```
<td width="65%" align="left">
    <form action="Student_Home.php" method="post">
        <input name="student_id" 
                   type="text" 
                   id="student_id">
    </form>
</td>
```